# How to label HTML for saving nested objects in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, body-parser

I have a model that looks like this:

```
const recipeSchema = new Schema({
title: { type: String , required: true},
description: { type: String , required: true},
steps:[{
    text:{type:String},
    ingredients:{type:String}
}]});
```

Using a bodyparser, I'm able to save data by simply tagging them in the name attribute of the HTML form. Like below:

```
<div class="input-field">
            <textarea id="title" name="title" placeholder="Enter title here"></textarea>
            <label for="title">Title</label>
</div>
```

This method works well for the first 2 fields (title and description), but I'm stuck on how to label them for the **steps** field. How would I make the code understand which input fields are for step.text and which are for steps.ingredient? And create an array of objects?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. For anybody else who may stumble across this post, here's how you do it.

Basically you need to refer to the object in the array as (per the example above) in the following format:

```
step[0][text]
```

I couldn't find it anywhere in the documentation, but finally got it from this link: 
http://www.thiscodeworks.com/how-to-save-input-from-html-form-to-json-file-using-body-parser-html-nodejs/5c44c4722178800014d5f127

Answer (score 0):

How are you passing your data to the html page? I think using a view engine like [EJS](https://ejs.co/) solves your problem better. It allows you to pass your data to a view, and then inject the data directly into your html elements.